# Google App Engine with GoLang "permission denied" error on Oauth2 autentification

Tags: google-app-engine, go, oauth-2.0

Oauth2 autentification library
Works well on the localhost but crashes when is uploaded to the Google App Engine

[oauth.go](http://code.google.com/p/goauth2/source/browse/oauth/oauth.go)

When it does the line 250 of the above code

`r, err := (&http.Client{Transport: t.transport()}).PostForm(t.TokenURL, v)`

The error response is "permission denied"

Answer (score 6):

From [the api.go documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-go-starter/source/browse/appengine/app/api/api.go?r=749cfb1ec838494751ff9b8199db22d2f7dc8032) :

> Since the Google App Engine URL Fetch API requires a per-request
>   context, you must use the *plus.Service from within an HTTP handler.
>   This package provides the WithNoAuthPlus and WithOAuthPlus functions
>   which you can use to wrap your HTTP handlers to provide them with
>   fully initialized *plus.Services.

Example:

```
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
trans := &oauth.Transport{
    Config:    oauthConfig,
    Transport: &urlfetch.Transport{Context: c},
}
trans.Exchange(code)
resp, err := trans.Client().Get(profileInfoURL)
```